# How to increase a XIB view based on it's contents?

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, xib

I have a `XIB` which is of this size: (width: 300, height: 100) while designing. It has 3 labels which will be expanding based on its content. I am simply loading that `XIB` and adding it to the `self.view`. Is there a way that I can easily increase the `XIB` view height as `UILabel` increases?

I have successfully able to increase my `UILabel`s as per the content.

I am using autolayout for `UILabel`s.

Constraints & settings:

XIB View:
[image]

Top Label:

[image]

Center Label:

[image]

Bottom Label:

[image]

Comment: your xib is defined as a class?

Comment: `class MyCalloutView: UIView { ... }` @ReinierMelian

Comment: You need to implement your class intrinsic content size method based on your view content, I think @AechoLiu answer can be helpful for you

Answer (score 1):

- Select the bottom most label or the one you think will define the height of your super view.
- Add bottom constraint of that label with super view.
- If you see any `Missing Constraints` error in xib file, just change the bottom constraint relation to `Greater Than or Equal` from `Equal`.

You are good to go.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I followed the exact steps and now no labels are increasing inside the XIB view itself. They all are having the one line.

Comment: Add screenshots of xib file and view constraints.

Comment: Added screenshots.

Comment: @Hemang Label constraints looks fine... How are you adding constraints when you add this xib file view in other view?

Comment: I am not adding any constraints when I will be adding the view to another view. It's just `self.view.addSubview`.

Comment: You have to add constrains specially leading, trailing and top constrains programatically because you are adding view programatically. If you don't add constraints frame of view will remain same always as it is in your xib file (300 x 100).

Answer (score 0):

I found some tutorials

1. [Self-sizing table view cell](https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells)
2. [Autolayout, dynamically resize UILabel](http://jayeshkawli.ghost.io/using-autolayout-to-dynamically-resize-uilabel/)

### My summary

A view's layout needs following constraints to decide his layout.

1. **Size**      
   width, and height
2. **Position**  
   x-axis, and y-axis position

And `UILabel`'s [intrinsicSize](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ViewswithIntrinsicContentSize.html) can decide his `Height` property. So, autolayout needs assign `Position`, and `Width` explicitly. 
After assign `text` to `UILabel`, call his `invalidateIntrinsicSize` to re-decide his `Height` property based on his content. And then, if his parent view (ex. `UITableViewCell`, or `UIView`) needs to decide his height based on his child `UILabel`'s height, then his parent's height will be dynamic based on his child `UILabel`.

Maybe his parent `UIView` needs to call `setNeedsLayout`, or `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` after calling `invalidateIntrinsicSize`.